# askbot-'askbot.deps.django_authopenid.forms.LoginForm object' has no attribute 'possword'

Tags: askbot

I have installed askbot app into my project. Now I login locally in askbot that is by providing "username & password". I see the following error:

`'askbot.deps.django_authopenid.forms.LoginForm object' has no attribute 'possword`'

**Traceback** tells that there is `value="{{ login_form.possword.value() }}"` line in the following file:

`askbot/templates/authopenid/signin.html in block "content"`

I didnot find that line at all.

**Complete HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="required login" id="id_password" 
        maxlength="128" name="password" type="password"
        {% if login_form.password.value() %}
        value="{{ login_form.possword.value() }}"
        {% endif %}
        placeholder="{% trans %}Password{% endtrans %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. There was a typo in the variable name. It was fixed [here](https://github.com/ASKBOT/askbot-devel/commit/9325371d64c12d95ada80171cc399d01a17313e9).